# Unity Animation Controller and walking diagonally keeps switching between the two diagonals?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites

Using Unity 2019.4.1f1 Personal.

[image: Unity Animation Controller nodes]

I have the above Animation Controller. When only walking in one direction at a time and when you stop you stay facing that direction, this works as planned.

[image: Successfully walking pokemon trainer]

All of the transitions do not have an exit time and have a fixed duration of 0. I don't know what info to give as this is the first time I've used animation. Let me know and I'll add relevant details.

Here's my update function that updates the variables in the animator:

```
void Update() {
  float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
  float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

  animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", h);
  animator.SetFloat("Vertical", v);

  if (Mathf.Abs(v) < Mathf.Abs(h)) {
    // flips the renderer to reuse other handed image
    spriteRenderer.flipX = h > 0;
  }

  // no actual movement until I figure this out
}
```

What I'm experiencing that I want to fix is when running diagonally:

[image: Broken diagonal movement]

It seems that when walking diagonally then the animator variables for `Horizontal` and `Vertical` are both either 1 or -1 and this causes the alternating of the sprites. What I'd like to happen is that the state machine would deterministically pick either N/S sprites or E/W sprites when moving diagonally. Turning on "Can Transition To Self" seems to properly pick a direction and stick to it but it fails to animate when only moving in a single direction. It looks like it's constantly transitioning to itself which starts over the cycle so I've left that unchecked on all transitions.

I'm not sure what the best way to fix this is. Most attempts I've tried so far complicate the state machine to the point it's unmaintainable. I also couldn't find anything about introducing priorities in a way that fixed the jitter.

What's the idiomatic Unity way to achieve clean diagonal movement in 2D?

Comment: Can you show us the conditions on one of your diagonal transition arrows, and one of the cardinal direction transition arrows for contrast? My guess is that the criteria that satisfy the diagonal transition *also* satisfy the criteria for two of your cardinal transitions, leading the transition from "Any State" to continually fire between them.

Comment: @DMGregory I do not have states for diagonal movement. What you describe sounds like what's happening. I was hopeful to reuse the existing N/S or E/W (I really don't care which directions are favored). Since all the conditions are a list of "<Variable> greater/less than <Value>" I assumed they were `or` logic and wouldn't help. If I can't define "condition AND condition" how would I even write a diagonal transition?

Comment: "I assumed they were `or` logic" Rather than assume, did you stop to experiment, or [check the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html)? "If your transition has one or more conditions, the conditions must *all* be met before the transition is triggered." Have you tried adding an extra condition to your horizontal state transitions to keep them from triggering when your vertical states are active?

Answer (score 1):

## The cause

Now you have selected that walk in some direction can be triggered from *Any State*. Thus, if you have `vertical = 1` and `horizontal = 1` in *WalkingNorth* state, your transition to *WalkingEast* is triggered (it meets the condition for `horizontal = 1`) and vice versa (transition to *WalkingNorth* is triggered when in *WalkingEast* state because of `vertical = 1`).

## Solution

Consider changing your animation state transitions, so that *Entry* points to *IdleSouth* - this will be your initial state. Then, make transitions from every *Idle_* state to every *Walking_* state based on triggers. Leave *Walking_* -> *Idle_* transitions intact. This will prevent you from going from *WalkingNorth* to *WalkingEast* when `horizontal = 1` and `vertical = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition as when any one of the input is not 0 then randomly assign a value to the animator.

If(h==1){
If(y==1){
Anim.SetFloat("Horizontal",0);
Anim.SetFloat("Vertical",1);
}else if(y==-1){
Anim.SetFloat("Horizontal",0);
Anim.SetFloat("Vertical",-1);
}}

Same could be done with h = -1

Comment: This answer would be better if it walked through the steps of how to do this, or showed an example in the inspector.

Comment: Hmm. This could be better

Comment: You probably want to add the conditionals in the animation transitions in the controller, not in the code.

Comment: Just add them in the script provided in the question above.